# IIIS 7.5 URL rewrite to Geoserver giving Connection Reset error

Tags: url-rewriting, jetty, iis-7.5, geoserver

I have Geoserver set up on a Windows 2008 server using Jetty as the web container on port 8080. If the browse to http://[servername]:8080/geoserver/www/test/test.html I get a html page returned as expected.

Then I have set up IIS 7.5 using ARR and URL rewrite at the application pool level, to set up a reserve proxy. So that http://[servername]/geoserver.. is rewritten to http://[servername]:8080/geoserver... I am using match '.*' for the url and 'geoserver/' for the condition.

This gives a error when browsed to of 'connection reset' IIS http error log (C:\Windows\System32\LogFiles\HTTPERR) shows 'Connection_Dropped DefaultAppPool'

If I change the url rewrite to an action of redirect, the html page is displayed as expect, but obviously the url shows as redirected to port 8080.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this by changing the URL rewrite to use .* for the URL match condition.